# ThreeJS: CatmullRomCurve3 is not rendering as expected

Tags: three.js, threejs-editor

I'm having a little issue here. I'm rendering a THREE.CatmullRomCurve3 but it is not rendering as per the points given.
Attaching the code snippet and the snip of the output here.

**Code snippet:**

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(95, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.5, 2000);
camera.position.copy( new THREE.Vector3(1070,-900,0));
camera.lookAt(1078.3760583512485, -896.7445069923997, -25.48);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor("#233143");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const points= [];
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1078.3760583512485, -896.7445069923997, -25.48));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1078.3294048905373, -896.5172636993229, -25.49));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1078.5533414967358, -895.2421761974692, -25.48));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1078.8612543307245, -894.7750648967922, -25.71));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1079.1878285482526, -894.7119417488575, -25.66));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1079.5797176100314, -894.6866924837232, -25.65));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1081.27790354006, -894.8381880447268, -25.66));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1088.4998590946198, -895.4946687817574, -25.68));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1100.3125150762498, -896.832879383117, -25.63));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1114.1126084402204, -898.2847114242613, -25.65));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1123.1353875361383, -899.1810597889125, -25.66));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1133.763045642525, -900.0900326892734, -25.68));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1141.0316546559334, -900.7465130649507, -25.68));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1141.0316546559334, -900.7465130649507, -24.75));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1141.1063001919538, -900.7591376900673, -24.74));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1147.6191231589764, -901.2136240750551, -24.74));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1150.7169128786772, -901.4282426387072, -24.73));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1158.1068208869547, -901.9206028580666, -24.74));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1159.9076444301754, -902.0468490608037, -24.74));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1169.6115640364587, -902.6275815851986, -24.72));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1172.2521498519927, -902.7790770195425, -24.73));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1183.6169326212257, -903.359809499234, -24.73));
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1189.868496214971, -903.6880495809019, -24.72));

// Rendering the curve
const randomSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);
const extrudeSettings = {
    steps: 30,
    bevelEnabled: false,
    extrudePath: randomSpline
};
const wallShape = new THREE.Shape();
const wallHeight = 1 / 2;
const wallWidth = 0.1 / 2;
wallShape.moveTo(-wallHeight, -wallWidth);
wallShape.lineTo(-wallHeight, wallWidth);
wallShape.lineTo(wallHeight, wallWidth);
wallShape.lineTo(wallHeight, -wallWidth);
const geo = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(wallShape, extrudeSettings);
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xFF5733 }));
scene.add(mesh);

// Line to vsualise the expected curve position
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF5733 } );
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(line);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

**Output: [Code Snippet Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jrXw.png)**

As seen in the output, the CatmullRomCurve3 is rendered in black color and also, to visualise the exact curve that's supposed to render I have rendered a THREE.Line as well giving it the same points as of the curve.
I suspect the curve is not rendering as expected as the given points are too proximal to each other. Any suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: `steps: 30`, try to set a greater value for this parameter.

Comment: @prisoner849, setting the steps to 500 does resolve this issue. But the application I'm working on renders about 2000, 5000 or even 10000 curves in the scene depending on the data we receive and rendering all of these curves with steps set as 500 is resulting in performance degradation. Is there any other way to avoid performance issues or any way to identify what value should be assigned to steps for each curve based on the points of the curve?